# Obtain HTTP_METHOD programatically inside WSO2 Custrom Handler?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have a custom authentication handler in which I need to figure out the HTTP_METHOD.

In my **custom mediators** I can get this easily from the synapse context, from api.ui.HTTP_METHOD property. For example

```
api.ut.HTTP_METHOD ==> POST
```

But I do not have this property in my **custom authentication handler**. Is there another way to get hold on the HTTP METHOD of the API inside a custom authentication handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a custom handler, you have access to the message context. Using that message context , you can retrieve HTTP_METHOD like below.

```
((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext().get‌Property("HTTP_METHOD")
```

Can refer [Writing Custom Handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Writing+Custom+Handlers) and [Axis2 Java doc](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.axis2.Constants.Configuration.HTTP_METHOD) for more info.